# Babel transpile required to run JSX code (ReactJS)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, babeljs

I'm having a look at some code I wrote a year ago and for all projects I get error on running index.js (in Atom, using 'script' package). I totally forgot how I ran those projects back then and haven't done any programming (with React) since then. Was it required to transpile this code with babel in order to run any JSX code?

[image]

index.js in /src:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

package.json:

```js
{
  "name": "jammming",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
    "react-scripts": "1.0.11"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

Why is this and how to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah as `JSX` is not standard syntax, it is a syntactic sugar for [React.createElement](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html).
You can use [babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx)

In

```
var profile = <div>
  <img src="avatar.png" className="profile" />
  <h3>{[user.firstName, user.lastName].join(' ')}</h3>
</div>;
```

Out

```
var profile = React.createElement("div", null,
  React.createElement("img", { src: "avatar.png", className: "profile" }),
  React.createElement("h3", null, [user.firstName, user.lastName].join(" "))
);
```

Comment: Thanks, good  to know! 

Since I was pretty sure I didn't use babel transpilation for this before I searched a bit further and found that back then I opened the app in the browser with command npm start (which runs command 'react-scripts start' due to entry in package.json) and that opens the app in the browser (on 'localhost:3000). Apparently the react-scripts package also somehow deals with JSX code.